# How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I would like to customize both the background and the border color of a grouped-style UITableView.

I was able to customize the background color by using the following:

```
tableView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

But the border color is still something I don't know how to change.

How do I customize these two aspects of the grouped-style table view?

Comment: It is important to ensure that the IBOutlet view of your UITableViewController is set or the transparency won't work!

Comment: Not sure how you got your line of code to work. tableView doesn't seem to have a contentView property.

Comment: **The thread is about UITableViewCell's background** and not about UITableView (like the question suggests). The real answer would be @dizy's answer.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In iPhone OS 3.0 and later `UITableViewCell` now has a `backgroundColor` property that makes this really easy (especially in combination with the `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` initializer). But I'll leave the 2.0 version of the answer here for anyone that needs it…

---

It's harder than it really should be. Here's how I did this when I had to do it:

You need to set the UITableViewCell's backgroundView property to a custom UIView that draws the border and background itself in the appropriate colors. This view needs to be able to draw the borders in 4 different modes, rounded on the top for the first cell in a section, rounded on the bottom for the last cell in a section, no rounded corners for cells in the middle of a section, and rounded on all 4 corners for sections that contain one cell.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to have this mode set automatically, so I had to set it in the UITableViewDataSource's -cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

It's a real PITA but I've confirmed with Apple engineers that this is currently the only way.

**Update** Here's the code for that custom bg view. There's a drawing bug that makes the rounded corners look a little funny, but we moved to a different design and scrapped the custom backgrounds before I had a chance to fix it. Still this will probably be very helpful for you:

```
//
//  CustomCellBackgroundView.h
//
//  Created by Mike Akers on 11/21/08.
//  Copyright 2008 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum  {
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop, 
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle, 
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom,
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle
} CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition;

@interface CustomCellBackgroundView : UIView {
    UIColor *borderColor;
    UIColor *fillColor;
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition position;
}

    @property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *borderColor, *fillColor;
    @property(nonatomic) CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition position;
@end

//
//  CustomCellBackgroundView.m
//
//  Created by Mike Akers on 11/21/08.
//  Copyright 2008 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CustomCellBackgroundView.h"

static void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect,
                                 float ovalWidth,float ovalHeight);

@implementation CustomCellBackgroundView
@synthesize borderColor, fillColor, position;

- (BOOL) isOpaque {
    return NO;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [fillColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [borderColor CGColor]);

    if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop) {
        CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(0.0f, rect.size.height - 10.0f, rect.size.width, 10.0f));
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, rect.size.height - 10.0f);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 0.0f, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 10.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
        CGContextClipToRect(c, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 10.0f));
    } else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom) {
        CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, rect.size.width, 10.0f));
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, rect.size.width, 0.0f);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width, 10.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
        CGContextClipToRect(c, CGRectMake(0.0f, 10.0f, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
    } else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle) {
        CGContextFillRect(c, rect);
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 0.0f, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, rect.size.width, 0.0f);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
        return; // no need to bother drawing rounded corners, so we return
    }

    // At this point the clip rect is set to only draw the appropriate
    // corners, so we fill and stroke a rounded rect taking the entire rect

    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    addRoundedRectToPath(c, rect, 10.0f, 10.0f);
    CGContextFillPath(c);  

    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1);  
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    addRoundedRectToPath(c, rect, 10.0f, 10.0f);  
    CGContextStrokePath(c); 
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [borderColor release];
    [fillColor release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

static void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect,
                                float ovalWidth,float ovalHeight)

{
    float fw, fh;

    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {// 1
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }

    CGContextSaveGState(context);// 2

    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect),// 3
                           CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);// 4
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;// 5
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;// 6

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2); // 7
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);// 8
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);// 9
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);// 10
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1); // 11
    CGContextClosePath(context);// 12

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);// 13
}
```

Comment: Could you help me using your code ? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309580/light-about-a-solution-to-draw-cell-rectangles/7309645#7309645

Comment: Why just not use seperatorColor? For me, it colors both the seperator line between cells and the border.

Comment: Rather than that drawRect CG arc paths, I used a clipped view with all corners rounded. I give it a negative Y for non-first rows and I make it over-height-ed for non-last rows.

Answer (score 34):

I know the answers are relating to changing grouped table cells, but in case someone is wanting to also change the tableview's background color:

Not only do you need to set:

```
tableview.backgroundColor = color;
```

You also need to change or get rid of the background view:

```
tableview.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: Hey thanks. You gave the correct answer for this question specifically.

Answer (score 24):

First of all thanks for this code. I have made some drawing changes in this function to remove corner problem of drawing.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [fillColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [borderColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);

    if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop) {

        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy ;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, maxy);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, miny, midx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, miny, maxx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, maxy);

        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        // Fill & stroke the path
        CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);        
        return;
    } else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom) {

        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny ;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy - 1;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, miny);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, maxy, midx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, maxy, maxx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, miny);
        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        // Fill & stroke the path
        CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);    
        return;
    } else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle) {
        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny ;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy ;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, miny);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, miny);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, maxy);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, minx, maxy);

        CGContextClosePath(c);
        // Fill & stroke the path
        CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);    
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line width with your code is about 2 px. When I try to set CGContextSetLineWidth to 1, it's still to thick. Why is this?

Comment: I got the same question? why it's thicker than the system one.

Answer (score 16):

Thank you for the code, it's just what I was looking for. I have also added the following code to Vimal's code, to implement the case of a CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle cell. (All four corners are rounded.)

```
else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle)
{
        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , midy = CGRectGetMidY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy - 1;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, midy);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, miny, midx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, maxy, minx, midy, ROUND_SIZE);

        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        // Fill & stroke the path
        CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);                
        return;     
}
```

Answer (score 13):

One thing I ran into with the above CustomCellBackgroundView code from Mike Akers which might be useful to others:

`cell.backgroundView` doesn't get automatically redrawn when cells are reused, and changes to the backgroundView's position var don't affect reused cells. That means long tables will have incorrectly drawn `cell.backgroundViews` given their positions.

To fix this without having to create a new backgroundView every time a row is displayed, call `[cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay]` at the end of your `-[UITableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`. Or for a more reusable solution, override CustomCellBackgroundView's position setter to include a `[self setNeedsDisplay]`.

Comment: Good idea about overriding -setPosition

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for this super helpful post. In case anyone out there (like me!) wants to just have a completely empty cell background in lieu of customizing it through images/text/other content in IB and cannot figure out how the hell to get rid of the dumb border/padding/background even though you set it to clear in IB... here's the code I used that did the trick!

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EditTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = cellIBOutlet;
        self.cellIBOutlet = nil;
    }

    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero] autorelease];
    [cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];

    ... any other cell customizations ...

    return cell;
}
```

Hopefully that'll help someone else! Seems to work like a charm.

Comment: There's a memory leak in your solution. You need to autorelease the view you're setting to `cell.backgroundView`.

Answer (score 7):

Much thanks to all who posted their code.  This is very useful.

I derived a similar solution to change the highlight color for grouped table view cells.  Basically the UITableViewCell's selectedBackgroundView (not the backgroundView).  Which even on iPhone OS 3.0 still needs this PITA solution, as far as I can tell...

The code below has the changes for rendering the highlight with a gradient instead of one solid color.  Also the border rendering is removed.  Enjoy.

```
//
//  CSCustomCellBackgroundView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum  
{
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop, 
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle, 
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom,
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle,
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionPlain
} CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition;

@interface CSCustomCellBackgroundView : UIView 
{
    CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition position;
 CGGradientRef gradient;
}

@property(nonatomic) CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition position;

@end



//
//  CSCustomCellBackgroundView.m
//

#import "CSCustomCellBackgroundView.h"



#define ROUND_SIZE 10


static void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect,
         float ovalWidth,float ovalHeight);


@implementation CSCustomCellBackgroundView


@synthesize position;

- (BOOL) isOpaque 
{
    return NO;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
 {
        // Initialization code
  const float* topCol = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
  const float* bottomCol = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);

  CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  /*
  CGFloat colors[] =
  {
   5.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 245.0 / 255.0, 1.00,
   1.0 / 255.0,  93.0 / 255.0, 230.0 / 255.0, 1.00,
  };*/
  CGFloat colors[]=
  {
   topCol[0], topCol[1], topCol[2], topCol[3],
   bottomCol[0], bottomCol[1], bottomCol[2], bottomCol[3]
  };
  gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, colors, NULL, sizeof(colors)/(sizeof(colors[0])*4));
  CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionTop) 
 {

        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy ;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, maxy);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, miny, midx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, miny, maxx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, maxy);

        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);

  CGContextSaveGState(c);
  CGContextClip(c);
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(minx,miny), CGPointMake(minx,maxy), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
  CGContextRestoreGState(c);

        return;
    } 
 else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom) 
 {

        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy - 1;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, miny);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, maxy, midx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, maxy, maxx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, miny);
        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);

  CGContextSaveGState(c);
  CGContextClip(c);
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(minx,miny), CGPointMake(minx,maxy), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
  CGContextRestoreGState(c);

        return;
    } 
 else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle) 
 {
        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy ;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, miny);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, miny);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, maxx, maxy);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, minx, maxy);
  // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);

  CGContextSaveGState(c);
  CGContextClip(c);
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(minx,miny), CGPointMake(minx,maxy), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
  CGContextRestoreGState(c);

        return;
    }
 else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionSingle)
 {
        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect) , midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) ;
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect) , midy = CGRectGetMidY(rect) , maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
        minx = minx + 1;
        miny = miny + 1;

        maxx = maxx - 1;
        maxy = maxy - 1;

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, minx, midy);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, miny, midx, miny, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, ROUND_SIZE);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(c, minx, maxy, minx, midy, ROUND_SIZE);
        // Close the path
        CGContextClosePath(c);              

  CGContextSaveGState(c);
  CGContextClip(c);
  CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(minx,miny), CGPointMake(minx,maxy), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
  CGContextRestoreGState(c);

        return;         
 } 
 else if (position == CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionPlain) {
    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) ;
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, CGPointMake(minx,miny), CGPointMake(minx,maxy), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    return;
}

}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void) setPosition:(CustomCellBackgroundViewPosition)inPosition
{
 if(position != inPosition)
 {
  position = inPosition;
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }
}

@end


static void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect,
         float ovalWidth,float ovalHeight)

{
    float fw, fh;

    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {// 1
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }

    CGContextSaveGState(context);// 2

    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect),// 3
         CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);// 4
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;// 5
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;// 6

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2); // 7
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);// 8
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);// 9
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);// 10
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1); // 11
    CGContextClosePath(context);// 12

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);// 13
}
```

Comment: This is really great and what I was looking for. I need two options though. set bg as gradient or solid color. I set the solid color just by setting both the gradient color to the same solid color I wanted. It impose unncecessary calculation  though. It would nice to have some options like that.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the border color by setting

```
tableView.separatorColor
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the table view border color:

In.h:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

In .m:

```
tableView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be easily done using [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit) by adding about 5 lines of code. If you use `nib` files or `storyboard`, also do not forget to apply [this little hack](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit/issues/3) . When you use this approach, you should subclass your cell from `PrettyTableViewCell`:

```
#import <PrettyKit/PrettyKit.h>

@class RRSearchHistoryItem;

@interface RRSearchHistoryCell : PrettyTableViewCell
```

This is example of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"RRSearchHistoryCell";

  RRSearchHistoryCell *cell = (RRSearchHistoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if ( cell == nil ) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RRSearchHistoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = topLevelObjects[0];
    cell.gradientStartColor = RGB(0xffffff);
    cell.gradientEndColor = RGB(0xf3f3f3);

  }

  RRSearchHistoryItem *item = _historyTableData[indexPath.row];
  [cell setHistoryItem:item];


  [cell prepareForTableView:tableView indexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I have been having problems with this and tried lots of combinations of things as I noticed that for some cells it worked fine but not for others.

Strangely I found out that it is possible to set the cell.backgroundColor to lightGrayColor and all works perfectly - but blueColor caused me problems of not updating the outside edges.

Unless it is really important to use green - perhaps you might want to try this. It might be that this is a feature to get people to use only grey colours when indicating a cell is selected.