# Set backgroundColor of UITableViewCell in grouped UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set the backgroundColor of a UITableViewCell in a grouped UITableView and maintain the rounded corners of the cells?

All of my attempts results in a loss of the rounded corners.

mike

Answer (score 6):

I asked the same question a few weeks ago, and you can see the valid answer here:

[How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)

It is indeed possible and the provided source code works great.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. I believe the rounder corners are a background with the cell being transparent at the edges. When you try to use a custom color (or image) it draws over them.