# How can I set the background color of a cell in UITableView on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I set the background color of a cell in UITableView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old post, but I am sure some people are still looking for help. You can use this to set the background color of an individiual cell, which works at first:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
     [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

However, once you start scrolling, the iphone will reuse cells, which jumbles different background colors (if you are trying to alternate them). You need to invoke the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath. This way, the background color gets set before the reuse identfier is loaded. You can do it like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     cell.backgroundColor = ([indexPath row]%2)?[UIColor lightGrayColor]:[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

The last line is just a condensed if/else statement. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Apparently the existing UITableViewCell framework makes it very difficult to change the background color of a cell and have it work well through all its state changes (editing mode, etc.).

A solution has been posted at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view), and it's being billed on several forums as "the only solution approved by Apple engineers." It involves subclassing UITableViewCell and adding a custom view for the subclassed cell's `backgroundView` property.

**Original post** - this solution doesn't work fully, but may still be useful in some situations

If you already have the UITableViewCell object, just alter its `contentView`'s `backgroundColor` property.

If you need to create UITableViewCells with a custom background color, the process is a bit longer. First, you'll want to create a data source for your UITableView - this can be any object that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

In that object, you need to implement the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, which returns a UITableViewCell when given an NSIndexPath for the location of the cell within the table. When you create that cell, you'll want to change the `backgroundColor` property of its `contentView`.

Don't forget to set the `dataSource` property of the UITableView to your data source object.

For more info, you can read these API docs:

- [UITableViewDataSource - `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)
- [UITableViewCell - `contentView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView)
- [UIView - `backgroundColor`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW30)
- [UITableView - `dataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource)

Note that registration as an Apple developer is required for all three of these links.

Comment: I have added this line in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];. It still shows black text on white background

Comment: I have tried cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor orangeColor]; this does not work either

Comment: As Rob said below, you want the contentView, not the backgroundView. My bad; edited to correct.

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor]; does not work either. It shows orange color at the two end of the cell, but I want orange color as a background. Could you let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundView is all the way on the bottom. It's the one that shows the rounded corners and the edges. What you want is the contentView which is on top of the backgroundView. It covers the usually white area of the cell.

Comment: Actually, I want to achieve the effect where one cell of the table view will have blue background, the next one will have white, the next one will have blue again, and then white and so on... could you let me know how can I do that?

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor]; does not work either. It shows orange color at the two end of the cell, but I want orange color as a background. Could you let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cell.subviews objectEnumerator];
id anObject;
while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if( [anObject isKindOfClass: [ UIView class] ] )
        ((UIView*)anObject).backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The version I wrote will work in iPhone 3.0 or higher and fallback to a white background otherwise.

In your `viewDidLoad` method of the `UITableViewController` we add the following:

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
// Also consider adding this line below:
//self.tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

When you are creating your cells (in my code this is my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) add the following code:

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"code_bg.png"]];
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version >= 3.0)
{
     [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set the `backgroundColor` of the `backgroundView`. If the `backgroundView` does not exists, you can create one for it.

```
if (!tableView.backgroundView) {
    tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.bounds];
}
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor theMostFancyColorInTheUniverse];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background of a cell to an image then use this code:

```
    // Assign our own background image for the cell
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.image = background;
cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
```