# Changing border color in iPhone UITableView cells (non-grouped)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've read (and used) the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view) which illustrates how to change the background color and border color of a UITableViewCell in grouped mode on the iPhone.  I'm writing an app now which has a non-grouped UITableView and I need to change the border color of the cells.  I know that I can modify the code and create a new background view and apply it, but is it necessary?

Is there an easy way to specify the border color of a UITableViewCell if it is a non-grouped style?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If by "border color" in a plain table view you mean the separator lines between the cells (default color gray), you can customize this color for the whole table view via:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

See the [UITableView reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614984-separatorcolor?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks.  I just couldn't find it.