# UITableViewCell with custom gradient background, with another gradient as highlight color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a custom layout.  I wanted a gradient background, so in my UITableViewDelegate cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, I create a CAGradientLayer and add it to the cell's layer with insertSubLayer:atIndex: (using index 0).  This works just fine except for two things:

Most importantly, I can't figure out how to change to a different gradient color when the row is highlighted.  I have tried a couple things, but I'm just not familiar enough with the framework to get it working.  Where would be the ideal place to put that code, inside the table delegate or the cell itself?

Also, there's a 1px white space in between each cell in the table.  I have a background color on the main view, a background color on the table, and a background color on the cell.  Is there some kind of padding or spacer by default in a UITableView?

Comment: There's a really good article over on [Cocoa with love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) about customising the look and feel of a table view. I think thank may answer your question.

Comment: best link ever...MUCH appreciated.  I'm really new to iPhone and porting an app from Android where I'm much more comfortable is proving to be pretty challenging.

Comment: For something simple, have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979165/applying-background-gradient-to-a-grouple-table-cell/7818298#7818298 For the different gradient for selected, it works fine to use the cell.selectionStyle in most cases (which can darken the gradient background when selected)

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at CAGradientLayer. Then you can get rid of all your images...

Answer (score 19):

I know this thread is old, but here's a solution for the first part of your question (adding a gradient to the selected and non-selected states of a cell):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    grad.frame = cell.bounds;
    grad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];

    [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer *selectedGrad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    selectedGrad.frame = cell.bounds;
    selectedGrad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];

    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedGrad atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: If you have a long table, this method will keep adding stuff to the same cell

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the first question but I think you can set the selectedBackgroundView property similarly to how you set the backgroundView property. The white space between cells is probably the separator. You can change that color like

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I tried that, but maybe not the right way.  Anyway, the link Derek provided above shows an example of setting tableView.separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone which is probably what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for days with this. The solution ended up being quite simple but the various parts of the puzzle were spread across several different answers and sites. The missing piece of the puzzle turned out to be the distinction between the content view and the background view and where the selection color is applied.

Features of my solution:

- I load my cell from a nib so that I can layout the content in IB. Feel free to lay out the content programmatically.
- I grab the gradient colors from a global style object because I need to customize the gradient by client.

  - I set the selection color of the cell to gray in the nib so the default (blue) does not clash with my color scheme.
- I add the gradients to the background view. If you don't do this, the selection color does not show correctly. UITableViewCell does not have a background view by default so you have to create it first.

This last point was the secret ingredient that made it all work for me.

I added a factory method to my UITableCellView subclass because I wanted to use the same cell in multiple tables.

```
+(ActivityDetailCellView *) createWithStyle: (WMStyle *) style {  
  UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] 
       initWithNibName: @"ActivityDetailCellView"
       bundle: nil];

  ActivityDetailCellView *cell = (ActivityDetailCellView *) temporaryController.view;

  CAGradientLayer *lightGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  lightGradient.frame = cell.bounds;
  lightGradient.colors = style.lightGradient;

  UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: cell.bounds];
  [background.layer insertSublayer:lightGradient atIndex:0];  
  cell.backgroundView = background;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution - I like the idea of containing it within the UITableViewCell subclass. One question though - what is (WMStyle *)?

Comment: I keep all my style-related settings (fonts, colors, gradients etc) in one class so that I can change them in one place.

Comment: Hi Kevin. That sounds great. Is it possible to post a simple example? Thanks Sean