# Using gradient as background in UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableViewCell with custom gradient background, with another gradient as highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634557/uitableviewcell-with-custom-gradient-background-with-another-gradient-as-highli)

Hey, I want to put a slight gradient background for my tableview cells to make them look more interesting. Should I just make image and put it on the background or use code to draw it? If If I should use code to do it could you explain how? PS. I got a custom cell

Answer (score 2):

Make the image first, say gradient.jpeg for instance.

Then get the following done inside your -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method where you configure your cells.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.jpeg"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

cell.backgroundView = imageView;

[imageView release];

And yes by make the image, I meant get it done on some capable image editor.

Comment: I can't seem to get it show on the back of my cell somehow. I am doing what you said, but it won't show :S

Comment: Might sound very silly on my part but have you added the image which you have created to the Resources folder of your project? If so, could you post some relevant code on what you are doing in the above method? I can help you out as the above most definitely worked for me in one of my projects :)