# Using gradient background in UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableViewCell with custom gradient background, with another gradient as highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634557/uitableviewcell-with-custom-gradient-background-with-another-gradient-as-highli)

Hey I am trying to use gradient as background of my tableView cell and I have tried using this code:

```
        UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
            CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
            gradient.frame = view.bounds;
            gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
            [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
            [cell setBackgroundView:view];
```

Any idea why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: Why the same question within 12 hours?

Comment: AppKit only exists in Cocoa. You are using UIKit. Also, please describe how exactly it “isn't working correctly”.

Comment: vikingosegundo: Same title, but a different, more-specific question.

Comment: Well how it isn't working correctly is that it isn't just showing.

Comment: Ok, so I see that it shows for a moment when I actually select the cell and it moves to next view. It somehow shows on the selected state.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the view directly to the cell, add it to the cell's `contentView`. This will ensure that when orientations occur, resizing occurs as expected and not some screwed up way. This will also ensure that, in other cases where you may have some other view (such as a scrollview) embedded in that view, it will actually scroll fluidly, etc. Things work as expected when they are placed where they're...expecting.

Comment: But when I try to put the view as background view it won't show up somehow :S I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: jer was instructing you NOT to use backgroundView. use contentView. the was also mentioned in a WWDC video