# Setting NavigationBar and TabBar background color with gradient in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, background-color

I want to set background color for NavigationBar and TabBar. It must be a gradient containing two hexadecimal colors. How can I made it in objective-c?
Thanks,

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

For the TabBar I had the same problem with my app and I came up with following:
in *applicationDidFinishLaunching* method I created a function to draw a gradient and used an instance of my UITabBarController to set up a correct gradient frame depending on the width of the device.

```
    - (UIImage *)drawGradientInView:(UITabBarController *) tabBarVC {
   CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

  gradient.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetMinY(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetWidth(tabBarVC.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame));

  gradient.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
  gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
  gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.bounds.size);
  [gradient renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return gradientImage;
}
```

get the instance of UITabBarController

```
UITabBarController *tabVC = (UITabBarController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject.rootViewController;
```

set your gradient

```
[UITabBar appearance].backgroundImage = [self drawGradientInView:tabVC];
```

I'm not sure if that's a correct approach but it did work for me.

For NavigationBar, I subclassed it and customised that in *layoutSubviews*

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) + CGRectGetHeight([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame));
    gradient.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.bounds.size);
    [gradient renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score -2):

This will help you to change the color of Navigation bar & Tab bar

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
...
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UITabBarController *tabBarCon;
...
tabBarCon.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: thanks for answer but the background color must be a gradient containing two hexadecimal color. How can i implement this?

Comment: I dont understand by gradient containing hexadecimal color. But I suggest you to please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979165/applying-background-gradient-to-a-grouple-table-cell) before you proceed.

Comment: You have two colors, which are the two endpoints, and the gradient should flow smoothly from the first color to the second. The only difference here is that realuser has two hex colors that he needs to use, not just a single color. This is essentially a custom gradient and there are other questions on SO that bring this up, just not so much with hex colors.

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question, I'm looking for the same thing