# UITableViewCell displaying incorrect alpha based background colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I have a UITableViewCell with the UITableViewStyleGrouped style and I would like to change the background color of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip {
    // Do cell creation stuff ...

    cell.backgroundColor = 
      [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:175.0/255.0 alpha:0.50];
}
```

The trouble is, this doesn't display properly on a grid with the `UITableViewStyleGrouped`; I use the same color on a `UITableViewStylePlain` and it displays correctly.  I'm developing for OS 3.0 and have read the [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784827/change-background-color-of-tableview-cell-uitableviewcell-got-the-code-work) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164459/changing-uitableviewcell-textlabel-background-color-to-clear) on setting background color.  I can set the color it just doesn't set properly!  What am I missing?

[image: Incorrect yellow background with Alpha]
[image: Correct yellow background with Alpha]

Comment: UITableViewCell does not have a backgroundColor property....  Could that be your problem?

Comment: @Chip It does, `backgroundColor` is inherited from `UIView`

Comment: Sure does.  Sorry.  Is this a custom subclass or a pre-defined style?

Comment: It isn't subclassed and I don't think I'm using a pre-defined style because I don't know what that means. `:P`  I'm simply creating a `UITableViewCell` instance and trying to set the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be doing something in your cell creation/reuse logic to change the default behavior.  Starting a project from scratch and implementing this code works for me:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

    return cell;
}
```

Double check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) if you need something more complex.

Also, could the color shift be coming because of the different table background colors in the two different styles?  A UITableViewStylePlain tableView has a default white background.  A UITableViewStyleGrouped tableView will have a gray background.  Since your are setting the alpha to 0.5, it will overlay onto two different color backgrounds and give you a color shift.

Comment: @Chip - Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try and see what happens.  I think you might be right about the overlay on the gray background color.  If that's the problem is there a solution for that?

Comment: If that's the issue, subclass the UITableViewCell.  You can then make "solid background cell" white and have a colored background with alpha in front of it.  Alternatively, if transparency is not really needed, figure out the opaque color of the cell and just set it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this method is not supported, but it does work. Close xcode, open the .xib or .storyboard file in a text editor such as vi. Find the XML for your table and change the cell colour. For example, here is the original section for a default white table cell:

```
<tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" indicatorStyle="black" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="k63-au-YAF">
  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
  <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
  <prototypes>
```

Find and change the color tag. Here is an example that includes the colours from the original post:

```
<tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" indicatorStyle="black" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="k63-au-YAF">
  <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
  <color key="backgroundColor" red="1.0" green="0.95294117647059" blue="0.68627450980392" alpha="0.5" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
  <prototypes>
```

Open xcode again and your cell colour has been updated.

Note: For the color codes, 243/255 = 0.95294117647059 (Green), 175/255 = 0.68627450980392 (Red), etc.