# drawRect not being called in my subclass of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have subclassed UIImageView and tried to override drawRect so I could draw on top of the image using Quartz 2D.  I know this is a dumb newbie question, but I'm not seeing what I did wrong.  Here's the interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImageViewCustom : UIImageView {

}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "UIImageViewCustom.h"

@implementation UIImageViewCustom

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // do stuff
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I set a breakpoint on `drawRect` and it never hits, leading me to think it never gets called at all.  Isn't it supposed to be called when the view first loads?  Have I incorrectly overridden it?

Comment: please see the updated answer, sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: okies. going through the documentation I observed it would work if you make a subclass of UIView instead of UIIMageView, now you can add the properties of UIImageView in your subclass, I did it once for drawing the background of my tableview cells , for more details you can check at.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784827/draw-a-custom-cell-for-tableview-uitableview-with-changed-colors-and-separa

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It'll only get called if the view is visible, and dirty. Maybe the problem is in the code that creates the view, or in your Nib, if that's how you're creating it?

You'll also sometimes see breakpoints failing to get set properly if you're trying to debug a "Release" build.

---

I somehow missed the first time that you're subclassing UIImageView. From the docs:

> Special Considerations
>
> The UIImageView class is optimized to
>   draw its images to the display.
>   UIImageView will not call drawRect: in a
>   subclass. If your subclass needs
>   custom drawing code, it is recommended
>   you use UIView as the base class.

So there you  have it. Given how easy it is to draw an image into your view using [UIImage drawInRect:], or by using CALayer, there's probably no good reason to subclass UIImageView anyway.

Comment: shouldn't drawRect get called when the view is first rendered, though?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, I remember reading that.  Don't know why I couldn't find it again when I was looking for it.  Thanks.

Comment: `UIImageView` is a great thing to be able to subclass if you want to work with IB. Sigh... thanks for the answer, it helps.

Comment: But on second thought, you can still subclass it. You just cannot mess with the drawing :)

Comment: Going on six years later, and the Swift 3.0.1/Xcode 8.2.1 template for a subclassing of UIImageView still has boilerplate commented out draw(_ rect: CGRect) function, wherein the comment says if you need to customize drawing just uncomment and add your custom drawing code. So, thank you, stackoverflow community!

Comment: Yes, the template system in Xcode is sadly under-developed. They could do so much more with it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

**Edit:**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES];//add this line also
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setNeedsDisplay{
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.frame];
}
```

into your code.

hope this helps.

Thanks,

madhup

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but may solve your problem:

Why do this with a subclass of UIImageView?  Subclassing can always be problematic, especially for classes that aren't designed to be subclassed--and I bet UIImageView isn't.  If you just want to draw stuff on top of an image, then create a view with a transparent background, draw whatever you want, and place it directly over the image.

Comment: OK, fine, I looked it up in the documentation and apparently subclassing it is fine.  I still suspect this isn't the best way to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific case, it could make sense to use a `UIButton` with a background image instead of a `UIImageView`. You could even set `userInteractionEnabled` to NO and the result would be indistinguishable from a UIImageView.

In this case your `UIButton` subclass would simply include:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  if (kSomethingSpecial) {
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedBackground.png"] 
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```

Disclaimer - I would only recommend this if you have plans to use the image as a button at least some of the time. I can't wholeheartedly endorse using a `UIButton` as a workaround for this drawRect behaviour in `UIImageView`, as I'm sure Apple has its reasons for writing their API this way, like Mark referenced.