# How to recognize a blank/invisible image using java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, invisible

I was wondering if it would be possible to recognize that a **BufferedImage** in java is a blank (invisible for a user in a browser) image.

Comment: Define "blank" does it have an alpha channel? Do you want a measure of homogeneity? Is "mostly white", "mostly blank" or "mostly transparent" invisible? On a white background, a uniform 5% grey (#F2F2F2) is quite visible but "boring".

Comment: i mean total transparent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612152/drawrect-not-being-called-in-my-subclass-of-uiimageview
check that may be its help you.

Answer (score 1):

You mean entirely transparent?

You could use the `BufferedImage.getAlphaRaster()` and traverse the pixels to check that they are all completely transparent.

Comment: ok, i am trying the traversing... but what does it mean if an image has no alpharaster? getAlphaRaster() for some images it returns null?

Comment: @edwin - then the image has no alpha channel and therefore cannot be transparent