# How to make a draw over an UIImageView (iOS4)

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimage, drawing

I am using XCode 4.0.2 for a iOS4 project.

I have a `MainView.xib` and a `MainViewController`.

I have inserted an `UIImageView` in the `MainView.xib` with an image.

In the Identity Inspector, I give the `UIImageView` a custom class Diagram.

I created two new file `Diagram.h` and `Diagram.c`. In `Diagram.m` I have inserted

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size); 
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
     CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
     CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
     CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);

     CGContextStrokePath(context);
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
     CGColorRelease(color);
 }
```

When I run the app, I can see the image (in `UIImageView`, but the drawing is not done. Perhaps is not called. How can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: If you remove the image, can you see the drawing that takes place in your `drawRect` method? i.e. Is the `UIImageView` drawing the image on top of your custom drawing.

Comment: No, there is no drawing under the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the official Apple docs

> Special Considerations
>
> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: on a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.

You can see more detail on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612152/drawrect-not-being-called-in-my-subclass-of-uiimageview)