# Drawing circles in Core Graphics - why isn't this working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to create a simple drawing app that creates circles wherever you put your finger, this is what I have:

```
@synthesize touchPos;
@synthesize coords;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    coords.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f, %3.0f", touchPos.x, touchPos.y];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, 10.0, 10.0));

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
}
```

I don't get any errors or warnings, it just doesn't draw anything. Also, the text box shows the coordinates wherever I'm touching, so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: what kind of class is that? UIView or UIViewController?

Comment: That's weird. drawRect: is the proof that this is the implementation of some UIView, however, a view has no .view property. (touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.view];)

Comment: Check if your drawRect gets called.

Comment: I got it working by putting this code in a UIView subclass. I didn't have to change anything except for the self.view. It should rather be self.

Comment: Added some NSLog stuff to see what's happening and what's not, apparently drawRect is never getting called. ?

Answer (score 3):

This code needs to be in a UIView subclass that is part of the current view hierarchy.

Comment: I added a subclass, but drawRect isn't getting called, so nothing gets drawn.

Comment: Did you create and add an instance of your view subclass to your current view hierarchy?  (alloc, initWithXYZ, addSubView, etc.)  Are that view's touch handlers getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Did you call addSubview to add this to the main view?
Did you call setNeedsDisplay for this view?

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612152/drawrect-not-being-called-in-my-subclass-of-uiimageview).

Make sure the frame is correct and within the **bounds** of the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `-drawRect:` isn't being called because, that's right, your writing this code in a UIViewController.  You need to make a subclass of `UIView` and move all of this drawing and event handling to it.  The only thing that you should need to change is `self.view`, since in a subclass of `UIView` you will just need to say `self`.  Once you have a custom `UIView` subclass, you can use interface builder to set the class of your `UIViewController` to your custom class.