# UIImageView subclass needs to handle resize

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, core-graphics

I am creating a UIImageView subclass to display an audio waveform. The approach is to load the file, do math, save a PNG file and then `self.image = thePNG`. The nice part about this is that on a resize or repaint the UIImageView will stretch the PNG and stretch quickly.

Now if the image is expanded too much then I need to recalculate the waveform to avoid visible pixelation. Since we know that [UIImageView does not call `drawRect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612152/drawrect-not-being-called-in-my-subclass-of-uiimageview), is there a method that is called during resize so that I can decide if redrawing is necessary?

P.S. When recalculating I will be [fading in the new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638831/fade-dissolve-when-changing-uiimageviews-image) after it is calculated. Hopefully this will be seamless to the user like Google Earth.

Comment: Is the user resizing the image manually or will it be done automatically? ie can you track pinch to zoom on the image?

Comment: Good question. This will be automatic. For example the interface is rotated and constraints make the view grow.

Comment: I am looking further, might be able to use KVO on the frame property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
}
```

The trade off with this is that it is not called for each frame of an animation, as pointed out by David Jeske in [Is there a UIView resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event)

---

Other ideas that didn't work:

- Override `setFrame:(CGRect)frame` discussed at [Is there a UIView resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event)
- Listen for key-value observation, discussed at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ococoa/UojAu8rclwo