# How do I fill the background color of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How do I fill the background color of a UITableViewCell?  I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Where are you putting that code? More info please!

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view ?

Comment: I don't think Se3fan should've gotten credit for an answer on a duplicate question.  No offense St3fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a backgroundView for `UITableViewCell` :

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
// release object
[bgView release];
```

You can change the selection background view of `UITableViewCell` the same way.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```

Comment: This works the best - other solutions I found did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background color though `UITableViewCell`'s `backgroundColor` property only works in a *Grouped* table view. So if your table view is in the *Plain* style then it won't work.

You can of course set the background color of the `UITableView`'s `contentView`. But then you probably have to do some additional work as the other subview (text labels and accessory views) have their own idea of background colors.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following snippet from the UITableViewCell documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

That should solve your problem.