# Grouped UITableView Custom Cell Corners

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView with custom cells loaded from nib files. They have the proper 300 px width (for grouped) and appear okay, except for one problem: square corners. The first and the last cell of each group is not appearing to have rounded corners as it should. I have tried setting the backgroundcolor of the tableview to clear, as well as the background of the view. I initialize it in a pretty standard way in my UITableViewController with

```
 self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

I put this in the ViewWillAppear method. I've also tried it in the viewDidLoad method and it made no difference. Any help on getting these corners rounded would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried setting the background color of the cells to clear?

Comment: just tried it, didnt work. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: i haven't dealt with the problem myself, but i've heard you have to manage custom cells corners yourself (usually w/ 3-4 custom background images - don't know if it's a requirement - just often a common solution)

Comment: I'd have to experiment: `cell.backgroundView = [UIImageView …` and `cell.selectedBackgroundView = …`

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view