# Add a gradient background to a table view cell in grouped mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, gradient

-Hello, how can I add a CAGradientLayer to a tableview cell. The table view is in grouped mode that means it can have rounded corners as well. I tried:

```
  CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
  gradientLayer.frame = cell.frame;

  gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                          [UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                          [UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];

  gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1], nil];


  gradientLayer.masksToBounds = true;

  [cell.backgroundView.layer addSublayer: gradientLayer];

  //[cell.contentView.layer addSublayer : gradientLayer];

  [gradientLayer release];
```

If I set `masksToBounds = true` does that in any way affect the layer's corner radius?

If I add to the contentview it hides everything from the cell. If I add to the backgroundview it almost never shows, when it shows it is without rounded corners and only in the bottom part of the first cell, I have no idea why.

I add the gradient layer in my 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 method. Is this the right way to do this? Will I have rounded corners without manually using some paths or something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does anyone knows how to add a rounded corners to the first and last cells after adding this gradient layer  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these pages

- http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-make-custom-drawn-gradient-backgrounds
- [How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)