# Light about a solution to draw cell rectangles

Tags: iphone, ios

[How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

After reading this post, i tried to use this solution. Here  is my code, in the tableViewDelegate methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   CustomCellBackgroundView *customBackground = [CustomCellBackgroundView alloc];

    [customBackground setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [customBackground setFillColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [customBackground setPosition:0]; //i'll deal with that later

    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:customBackground];
    [customBackground release];


    UIImageView* selectedBackgroundCell = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
    [selectedBackgroundCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg_50_hover.png"]];
    [customBackground drawRect:selectedBackgroundCell.frame];

    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundCell];

    //standard background color
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg_50.png"]]];
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that whenever make views then you should specify some frame for that.
So specify frame CGRectZero for both custom background and background....

Following just work for me when I tested.

```
    UIView *bkview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];

    bkview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bkview;
```

Comment: Thanks for writing.... I it with code and changed my answer. Please check weather it is helpful or not....

Comment: don't forget to send an `autorelease` to bkview!

Comment: yes this works. But it's not the purpose of the question. It's not nice if the cells are grouped (try it). That's why I used the former post (see the first line of mine)

Answer (score 0):

You release customBackground and then you call [customBackground drawRect:selectedBackgroundCell.frame];

So obviously, calling the function on a nil pointer won't do anything.