# Customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view using the solution of a previous post

Tags: iphone, ios, background

I've read this post : [How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

And I want to display a background cell. So I'm trying a use the previous post in the `tableView` function `willDisplayCell`.

No matter what I do, nothing is working. Could you help me out ? (My cells are 50pt high.)

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question should indicate what you're asking.. I suggest you edit it.

Comment: are delegate and datasource connected to file's owner properly

Comment: yes everhything is doing fine, except the background which is not rounded.

Answer (score 1):

That question was posted two and a half years ago? for OS2 and then OS3. Probably not valid for OS4 or OS5.

An Apple engineer told me not to override drawrect like this as it was a "hack" and would likely break in a future OS version. So I would avoid doing that.

Comment: I know. But I want to use this solution in a different purpose : to change the SELECTEDBACKGROUND for a grouped tableView, because there is no elegant solution for it for the moment.