# Add shadow to a grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, shadow

I´m trying to add a shadow to a grouped UITableView (above each section) like i.e the twitter app. I found this two questions

[Grouped uitableview with shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912904/grouped-uitableview-with-shadow)

[How could I add a shadow to a grouped UITableView (as seen in the official twitter app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627146/how-could-i-add-a-shadow-to-a-grouped-uitableview-as-seen-in-the-official-twitt)

but any solutions work for me (I don't want to use images...).

I´ve tried to subclass UITableView, implement layoutSubviews and add one uiview (empty with rounded corners and shadow) for each section like question 1. The problem is that the shadow of the added views appears clipped (only visible at the top and bottom of the section) even if the cells are empty.

In my second attempt I've tried to subclass the cells, add a property that indicates when the cell is "alone", top, mid or bottom and add a proper custom backgroundView to the cell. I add the shadow to this custom backgroundView through it´s layer. The problem with this solution is that the shadows overlaps (sides) and I need to clip the shadows at the bottom of the top cells, at the top of the bottom cells and so on...

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a project solving this issue that works perfect:

https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit