# BackgroundView does not adapt round corner in Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am learning how to use storyboard and i am trying to build a UITableViewCell with grouped style. I tried to put a png file and set it as background for the cell. 
My png file is a rectangular image. 
When i open it in simulator, I found the first cell corner become a rectangle rather than a round corner cell. 
What should i can in order to make the first and last cell to be corner rounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know problem when using Grouped TableView.

You can either use the `backgroundColor` of `UITableViewCell` or you will have to draw the background by hand and check wether is the first of last in the section and add the rounded corners.

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view) post

Comment: You could also use a CAShapeLayer as a mask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the property `clippingSubviews` of your cells to `YES`.