# Create grouped UITableviewCell with custom selection Color and Border

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I'm currently writing an App which uses different selection Colors in a grouped Table View. This works great as far as it comes to Borders. 
I'm able to change Selection Color with the Code in this Post:
[How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400965/1199089)

**BUT** I'd like to additionally have the nice Border around the Cells that Apple uses. How can I use this Border?

http://www.mediafire.com/?x2gxbkjqu4d2zto

This is the Code to create the Background - mostly copied from above Post:
http://www.mediafire.com/?kltwlni1mf4t7ks

And this is how I use it:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [[[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0] indexPathByAddingIndex:1];
CGRect frame = [[self tableView] rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
TLCustomCellBackgroundView * selectedBackgroundView = [[TLCustomCellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[selectedBackgroundView setPosition:CustomCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom];
[[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
```

As you can see I nearly got it working correctly except of the gray Border around the second Cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution to this. it is not totally the same (as UITableviewCell in grouped Style got a even more sophisticated Design in iOS5 but this is sufficient to me. I borrowed this Approach from 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html

and it works great!

The code I used is: http://www.mediafire.com/?mdxkpfe8g74ctk9

Hope this helps others

Comment: Unfortunately you're right - It's quite a bit since I uploaded them.... Unfortunately I don't have them lying around anymore. I switched to a new approach with totally custom designed images and use setBackgroundView function of UITableviewcell in order to set the view!

Answer (score 2):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can set the Borders (Separator) for each row/section.

```
 if(indexPath.row == 1)
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 if(indexPath.section == 2)
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Just remember to set/reset this for each row/section you want it.

If you want to add the gray border around your red cell it would be

```
if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1){
//assuming this is the correct index)  
   [tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor  colorWithRed:0.67 green:0.67 blue:0.67 alpha:1];
}
else
{
   [tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor yourChosenDefaultColor]];
}
```

You actually need to use this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath or you're going to set the border for your whole TableView (maybe thats what you want to do)

Comment: Well I guess this is used for normal TableViews, but not for grouped Style TableViewCells.. Unfortunately that doesn't work...

Comment: I'm using it the same way in my grouped TableViews. Show some code and I'll try to help

Comment: Well Then I'm missing something else... I uploaded the Code. Thanks for your Help

Comment: Thanks! as you can see in the comment on my Question I managed to draw this border. I'm not sure wether your Solution works, because I'm changing the Background View and a quick try did not change anything. Nevertheless thanks for answering.