# how can i change ios table group border?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I want to get rid of this white border or colorize it to black.

As you see on the image, i want to change the white borders those shown in red circles.

How can i change it?

[image]

after adding this cote to tableview controller's viewDidLoad method;

```
[self.tuzukCell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.tuzukCell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

the resulting border is:

[image]

Comment: Try `tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];` also try to set tableview background color as black or clear color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/401271/1730272. What about tableview.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor]; and tableview.backgroundView = nil;?

Comment: they just clear the whole background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for static cell.. all of these methods .. must be setup in the storyboard file..

so..
click on storyboard file / Table view / Separator "none" / and choose desired color..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCell` `contentView's` underlying `CALayer`

Firstly import `QuartzCore`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Add this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `UITableView` delegate method

```
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor]; //any color u want to....
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f]; //set its width here
```

**EDIT** :Use this property according to requirement if tableview is static:

```
separatorStyle  property
separatorColor  property
backgroundView  property
```

Comment: And damn, too slow again ! ;)

Comment: Table is static. Where should i put it instead?

Comment: table is static there is no cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: but i put it in viewDidLoad function, it put a border however but it is not as i wanted :)

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you look at the third cell "Tuzuk". It drawed a border line but it does not cover the place that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, try this (after you init your cell) :

```
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Of course you can change `blackColor` to any other UIColor.

You can also do :

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

If you just wan to hide it.

Comment: table is static. Where should I put this then?

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you look at the third cell "Tuzuk". It drawed a border line but it does not cover the place that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

the following code will change the separator color, which means that it will change the separator line between the cell and the border itself.

try this to change it to black:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

or to remove it:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: use the code in the viewDidLoad if it did not work try [tableView setseparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];