# How to remove UITableViewCell border using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder, storyboard

I want to know if is there a way to remove the border in a `UITableViewCell` (grouped style) using the Interface Builder and storyboard.
I'm using static cells too.

does this have to be made by code?

thanks!!

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible through IB, but [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202965/removing-cell-borders-from-a-section-of-grouped-style-uitableview/5818622#5818622) might help you

Comment: Yes, it worked but I want to remove the border in only one UItableViewCell.

Comment: are you talking about the separator?  you can remove all via IB/SB, but if you want to remove just one, you'll have to remove all in IB/SB and the programmtically add a 1px uiview to the uitableviewcell view for all but the one you want to not have a border.

Comment: maybe will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13414153/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu, thanks but i just want to change one cell. It's not possible by Interface Builder... I think.
Thanks for the help one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two cell types and assign accordingly.