# Grouped Style UITableView doesn't clip subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a design issue with grouped uitableview, I add uiviews to the leftmost side of each cell extending little over the cell bounds and I want them to be clipped. But neither setting clip subviews in IB nor setting clipsToBounds property in code didn't help.

So far I have set clipsToBounds (for both uitableview itself and individual uitabviewcells) in a number of places but none helped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [cell setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defaultIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:defaultIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    ...
    [cell setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
    ...
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [mainTableView setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
}
```

Is it possible without changing tableview style to plain?

Comment: Try cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;  (this is a guess)

Comment: Got a screenshot? The "cell" is the full width of the table (i.e. it includes the grey bits at the left/right).

Answer (score 0):

Update: My previous answer was wrong. Here is an answer that actually shows how to do what you're asking.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/401271/350467

.......

Previous Answer

If you're adding views to the cell's contentView (which you should be, unless you have a good reason), you'll want to set `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;`