# Styling a Grouped Static TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

i have a Grouped Cells Static TableView and i'd like to know how to archieve this design? The border and the shadow.

[image: tableview]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must UITableViewCell override `drawRect`.

but, here is good Library. [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit).

Using a this you'll be able to easily reach.

Answer (score 2):

Without custom `drawRect` code you can't change the background of a cell.

There's a [GitHub project](https://github.com/sburlot/tableviewcellwithbkgnd) based on the answer provided at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view).

Basically you have to draw three different types of custom cells based on the position of the cell (top, middle, bottom).  I keep hoping each release of iOS will allow you to do this in a more direct manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can change cell's backroundView value:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:5.0];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
[imageView setImage:image];
self.backgroundView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Also you can change selectedBackgroundView value.