# How to customize UITablecell

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to customize a grouped `UITableViewCell`? I need to create a customized `UITableViewCell` but i can't change the separator style and add a shadow.

The thing that i got is (right) and what i want is on the left side. So i changed the separator style but i still got the other white line under it. So my question is how can i remove (or change color) the second white line (separator and the one under the cell) and how can i add a shadow?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to customize grouped table view is to ask a designer to draw nice cells and to use them in your app. Not to play with cell's properties and quarts/core layer

Comment: I believe you should subclass the UITableView. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1031593/312312

Comment: Have you work with Custom tableCell? Everything you can do in it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the separator *color,* you can use `[UITableView setSeperatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];`.

For the shadow, I'm betting they are using an image for the last cell in each section and setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO`.

Great job replicating the original, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

change the     tableChatList.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
and change the back ground colour of uitableview to clear color .